# Two digit positive numbers that satisfy $x+y=N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was recently being bored so I decided to play with some numbers. I found an interesting thing.

> How many two digit positive numbers are there where $x+y=N$ is true$?$

Here, 
$x=$product of the two digits 
$y=$sum of the two digits 
$N=$the number itself

---

What should be the correct approach for tackling this problem$?$ I have found one such number so far and that is $69$. I've been stuck on $69$ for quite a long time. You can see that $$\boxed{\color{red}{(6×9)+(6+9)=69}}$$

How to find more$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now that you've seen how to solve this, can you prove that there are no other solutions with a different number of digits?

Comment: @ChrisLewis yeah...I guess so...the main thing was to expand the number and then form equations ...I guess we can do that to any number of digits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ab+a+b =10a+b$ with $0 <a < 10$ and $0\leq b< 10$. Or equivalently, $9a = ab$. Implies, $b=9$ as $a$ cannot be zero. Now, in place of $a$ you put whatever the number, say for example $a=1$. Then $(1\times 9)+(1+9) = 19$. Similarly $(2+9)+(2\times 9) = 29$.

Answer (score 4):

This is really the equation $ab+a+b = 10a+b$, where $a,b\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$. Clearly, this can be simplified to $ab-9a=0$ or $a(b-9)=0$. Assuming you want a genuine 2-digit number so that $a\neq 0$, then we need $b=9$ but can then pick $a$ to be anything from $1$ to $9$.